# Unable to access “Seagate Expansion Drive” 2 T.B

Tags: external-hdd

I bought a Seagate Expansion 2TB External Hard disk to use among cross platform O.S but before my use I did not bother to do any settings or mount(if there was any or necessary) and I plugged it in to my laptop which has Ubuntu 13.10 in it. It worked fine when I did the transfer from my laptop to the external hard drive(seagate 2 t.b) but suddenly it shows me an error message(screen shot below). In the launcher the Icon appears but unable to perform any task.What do I do please suggest? I have already transferred my entire files in it, don't wanna lose it. And also How to do the partition so that it can be use for Other O.S as well?I am also a newbie please be detail in explaining. Thanks in advance.![Can't post  images so I'm listing the errors:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/koyu/Seagate Expansion Drive: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/koyu/Seagate Expansion Drive"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

Comment: Have you tried running `chkdsk /f` on Windows?

Comment: No. Because I don't have other O.S to try to or look for any errors. Isn't there any way to fix on ubuntu 13.10? Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check NTFS with ntfsfix in Ubuntu/Linux.

Open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs
```

then type as

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdbXX
```

XX indicate your device ID , you can find it with `df -h`

[Credit goes here](http://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2011/09/20/howto-fix-an-ntfs-partition-in-ubuntu/)

Comment: O.K. Thanks but after "sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs" resultbelow                                              koyu@koyu-K52F:~$ sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs
[sudo] password for koyu: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ntfsprogs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ntfsprogs' has no installation candidate
koyu@koyu-K52F:~$ 
  What do I do? Help.

Comment: @user279506 Try running this.
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs`

Comment: Sorry but the following message shows:                    emo@emo-K52F:~$ sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs
[sudo] password for emo: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ntfsprogs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ntfsprogs' has no installation candidate
koyu@koyu-K52F:~$                                                  Please how do I resolve this? Thanks for your time.

Comment: try with `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g` then try that answer

Comment: O.K.I don't know who you are but that command really worked like a charm(sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdbXX) and now I can view my files and do  the transferring.One last question, what do I have to do in order to use my External hard disk among crossplateform O.S( any settings or formatting)?And how to make multiple partition?Thank you very much Raaz.I appreciate your time and patience.

Comment: Cross Platform : NTFS,FAT are mostly accessible. in Linux EXT are default but now a days max Debain dists have support to NTFS by default . but some redhat dist support ntfs but some or not by default. But over all i suggest you to have a NTFS partition so that you can access it on both windows and linux. To format and partition  you can Gparted.( sudo apt-get install gparted) & Finally if my answer helped you , you can consider accepting it by the green tick mark

Comment: Why there is no option as "safe eject" on the application launcher for my External Hard Drive but an "unmount" option?

Comment: If you are trying to unmount while your device is in some data operation it will say its busy and it wont let you take it. unmount is pretty do safe eject here

Comment: I tried the command    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs and receive the same message.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the Seagate Expansion HDD 4TB ver. It would freeze Ubuntu and the disk was not accessible. I updated to kernel 3.16 and the problem went away.